# Emit action, then request and emit another with redux-observable and rxjs

Tags: redux, rxjs, redux-observable

So, I have an epic that receives a SUBMIT_LOGIN action and then it should fire the generateDeviceId function that returns an action with an id as payload. After that is processed by the reducer and the store is updated, it should request the login, then resolve it to store and finally redirect the user to our dashboard

```
const generateDeviceId = (deviceId)  => (({type: GENERATE_DEVICE_ID, payload: deviceId}));

const resolveLogin = (response) => ({type: RESOLVE_LOGIN, payload: response});

const submitLogin = (email, password) => ({type: SUBMIT_LOGIN, payload: {email, password}});

const requestLogin = (email, password) => ({type: REQUEST_LOGIN, payload: {email, password}});

const loadAbout = () => ({type: LOAD_ABOUT});

const submitLoginEpic = (action$) =>
        action$
            .ofType(SUBMIT_LOGIN)
            .mapTo(generateDeviceId(uuidv1()))
                .flatMap(({payload}) => login(payload.email, payload.password)
                    .flatMap(({response}) => [resolveLogin(response.content), loadAbout()])
                );
```

**ps: `login` function is an `ajax` from `rx-dom` that returns a stream:**

```
const AjaxRequest = (method, url, data) => {

    const state = store.getState();
    const {token, deviceId} = state.user;

    return ajax({
        method,
        timeout: 10000,
        body: data,
        responseType: 'json',
        url: url,
        headers: {
            token,
            'device-id': deviceId,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    });

};



 const login = (email, password) => AjaxRequest('post', 'sign_in', {email, password});
```

**ps2: `uuidv1` function just generates a random key (its a lib)**

I think (actually I'm sure) that I'm doing it wrong, but after two days i don't really know how to proceed. :/

### **UPDATE**

After Sergey's first update I've changed my epic to that, but unfortunately for some reason `rx-dom's` ajax is not working like Sergey's `login$` observable. We're currently working on this.

```
const generateDeviceId = (deviceId)  => (({type: GENERATE_DEVICE_ID, payload: deviceId}));

const resolveLogin = (response) => ({type: RESOLVE_LOGIN, payload: response});

const submitLogin = (email, password) => ({type: SUBMIT_LOGIN, payload: {email, password}});

const requestLogin = (email, password) => ({type: REQUEST_LOGIN, payload: {email, password}});

const loadAbout = () => ({type: LOAD_ABOUT});

const submitLoginEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(SUBMIT_LOGIN)
    .mergeMap(({payload}) =>
      Observable.of(generateDeviceId(uuid()))
        .concat(login(payload.email, payload.password)
          .concatMap(({response}) => [resolveLogin(response.content), loadAbout()])
```

### **UPDATE 2**

After Sergey's second update I've changed my code again and ended up with a solution where I use `two epics` and `.concatMap` operator in order to `synchronously` dispatch the actions and it `works as expected`.

```
const generateDeviceId = (deviceId)  => (({type: GENERATE_DEVICE_ID, payload: deviceId}));

const resolveLogin = (response) => ({type: RESOLVE_LOGIN, payload: response});

const submitLogin = (email, password) => ({type: SUBMIT_LOGIN, payload: {email, password}});

const requestLogin = (email, password) => ({type: REQUEST_LOGIN, payload: {email, password}});

const loadAbout = () => ({type: LOAD_ABOUT});

const submitLoginEpic = (action$) =>
  action$
    .ofType(SUBMIT_LOGIN)
    .concatMap(({payload}) => [
      generateDeviceId(uuid()),
      requestLogin(payload.email, payload.password)
    ]);

const requestLoginEpic = (action$) =>
  action$
    .ofType(REQUEST_LOGIN)
    .mergeMap(({payload}) => login(payload.email, payload.password)
      .concatMap(({response}) => [resolveLogin(response.content), loadAbout()])
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I got it right, you want your epic to produce the following sequence of actions in response to each `SUBMIT_LOGIN`:

```
GENERATE_DEVICE_ID -- RESOLVE_LOGIN -- LOAD_ABOUT
```

Also, I guess that `GENERATE_DEVICE_ID` needs to be issued immediately after `SUBMIT_LOGIN` is received,
while `RESOLVE_LOGIN` and `LOAD_ABOUT` should be issued only after a stream returned by `login()` emits.

If my guess is correct, then you just need to start the nested observable (the one created per each `SUBMIT_LOGIN`)
with `GENERATE_DEVICE_ID` action and `startWith` operator does exactly that:

```
const submitLoginEpic = action$ =>
    action$.ofType(SUBMIT_LOGIN)
        .mergeMap(({ payload }) =>
            login(payload.email, payload.password)
                .mergeMap(({ response }) => Rx.Observable.of(resolveLogin(response.content), loadAbout()))
                .startWith(generateDeviceId(uuidv1()))
        );
```

**Update:** one possible alternative could be to use `concat` operator: `obs1.concat(obs2)` subscribes to the `obs2` only when `obs1` has completed.

Note also that if `login()` needs to be called after `GENERATE_DEVICE_ID` has been dispatched, you might want to wrap it in a "cold" observable:

```
const login$ = payload =>
    Rx.Observable.create(observer => {
        return login(payload.email, payload.password).subscribe(observer);
    });

const submitLoginEpic = action$ =>
    action$.ofType(SUBMIT_LOGIN)
        .mergeMap(({ payload }) =>
            Rx.Observable.of(generateDeviceId(uuidv1()))
                .concat(login$(payload).map(({ response }) => resolveLogin(response.content)))
                .concat(Rx.Observable.of(loadAbout()))
        );
```

This way `GENERATE_DEVICE_ID` is emitted before `login()` is called, i.e. the sequence would be

```
GENERATE_DEVICE_ID -- login() -- RESOLVE_LOGIN -- LOAD_ABOUT
```

**Update 2:** The reason why `login()` works not as expected is because it depends on an external state (`const state = getCurrentState()`) which is different at the points in time when `login()` is called and when an observable returned by `login()` is subscribed to. `AjaxRequest` captures the state at the point when `login()` is called, which happens before `GENERATE_DEVICE_ID` is dispatched to the store. At that point no network request is performed yet, but `ajax` observable is already configured based on a wrong state.

To see what happens, let's simplify the things a bit and rewrite the epic this way:

```
const createInnerObservable = submitLoginAction => {
    return Observable.of(generateDeviceId()).concat(login());
}

const submitLoginEpic = action$ =>
    action$.ofType(SUBMIT_LOGIN).mergeMap(createInnerObservable);
```

When `SUBMIT_LOGIN` action arrives, `mergeMap()` first calls `createInnerObservable()` function. The function needs to create a new observable and to do that it has to call `generateDeviceId()` and `login()` functions. When `login()` is called, the state is still old as at this point the inner observable has not been created and thus there was no chance for `GENERATE_DEVICE_ID` to be dispatched. Because of that `login()` returns an `ajax` observable configured with an old data and it becomes a part of the resulting inner observable. As soon as `createInnerObservable()` returns, `mergeMap()` subscribes to the returned inner observable and it starts to emit values. `GENERATE_DEVICE_ID` comes first, gets dispatched to the store and the state gets changed. After that, `ajax` observable (which is now a part of the inner observable) is subscribed to and performs a network request. But the new state has no effect on that as `ajax` observable has already been initialized with an old data.

Wrapping `login` into an `Observable.create` postpones the call until an observable returned by `Observable.create` is subscribed to, and at that point the state is already up-to-date.

An alternative to that could be introducing an extra epic which would react to `GENERATE_DEVICE_ID` action (or a different one, whichever suits your domain) and send a login request, e.g.:

```
const submitLogin = payload => ({ type: "SUBMIT_LOGIN", payload });

// SUBMIT_LOGIN_REQUESTED is what used to be called SUBMIT_LOGIN
const submitLoginRequestedEpic = action$ =>
    action$.ofType(SUBMIT_LOGIN_REQUESTED)
        .mergeMap(({ payload }) => Rx.Observable.of(
            generateDeviceId(uuidv1()),
            submitLogin(payload))
        );

const submitLoginEpic = (action$, store) =>
    action$.ofType(SUBMIT_LOGIN)
        .mergeMap(({ payload }) => {
            // explicitly pass all the data required to login
            const { token, deviceId } = store.getState().user;
            return login(payload.email, payload.password, token, deviceId)
                .map(({ response }) => resolveLogin(response.content))
                .concat(loadAbout());
        });
```

#### Learning Resources

As `redux-observable` is based on RxJS, it makes sense to get comfortable with Rx first.

I highly recommend watching ["You will learn RxJS"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uQ1zhJHclvs) talk by André Staltz. It should give an intuition of what observables are and how they work under the hood.

André has also authored these remarkable lessons on egghead:

- [Creating Observables from scratch](https://egghead.io/courses/rxjs-beyond-the-basics-creating-observables-from-scratch)
- [Operators in Depth](https://egghead.io/courses/rxjs-beyond-the-basics-operators-in-depth)
- [Use Higher Order Observables in RxJS Effectively](https://egghead.io/courses/use-higher-order-observables-in-rxjs-effectively)

Also Jay Phelps has given [a brilliant talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AslncyG8whg) on `redux-observable`, it definitely worth watching.

Comment: Hey Sergey, thanks for the answer! I have tried .startWith but the problem is that `GENERATE_DEVICE_ID` should be emitted before the Login request.

So the orther is: 
`GENERATE_DEVICE_ID -- Login Request -- RESOLVE_LOGIN -- LOAD_ABOUT`

login(payload.email, payload.password) < -- This is the login request

Comment: Hey Lucas! Do you mean that `login()` depends or somehow needs generated device id to be in the store? Should `LOGIN_REQUEST` action be dispatched to the store too? Could you also clarify: does the `login()` sends the request immediately when called or only when the observable it returns is subscribed to? I updated the answer with a solution that uses `concat` operator, hope this helps.

Comment: Your updated answer fits like a glove! Thats exactly what I needed and solved my problem. But there is one thing that I still don't understand: I'm using `rx-dom's ajax` on my request so I bet that it should return a subscribed observable that would do what you're doing on `$login`, but when I tried to remove `$login` and use `rx-dom's`, it just didn't wait for `GENERATE_DEVICE_ID` to be in the store. Any idea why?

Comment: That sounds strange. `Rx.Observable.ajax()` does not cause any network request until observable it returns is subscribed to. In our case it would be subscribed only after `Rx.Observable.of(generateDeviceId(...))` completes, because of how `concat` operator works. Could you shed some light on how your `login()` function is implemented? It should not do any side effects, subscriptions, etc., but rather just return an observable, e.g. `const login = (email, password) => Rx.Observable.ajax(url(email, password));`

Comment: I've edited my question with both the `rx-dom's ajax` config and `login()` function and I think I'ts right... I'll update it again and post my new `submitLoginEpic`. I'd like to also ask if you know some place where I can learn more about how operators flux works and when should I use each one of them

Comment: Lucas, I updated my answer with some thoughts on why `login()` doesn't work as expected and how to overcome that. In a nutshell: `login()` uses external state to initialize `ajax` observable, but gets called before `GENERATE_DEVICE_ID` is dispatched and thus ends up with an obsolete data. I also added several links to learning materials that I myself found really helpful.

Comment: Sergey, I'm really grateful for your time and help in here. This thread really helped me to have a better understanding on how `RxJS` works and right now I'm diving into the `docs` and your `learning resources`. Hope this can be useful for you as it was for me. See ya!

Comment: Lucas, you're welcome! I'm glad that I could help. Good luck!